# Unable to install Laravel in ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, composer

When i run `composer` in terminal,

```
Cannot create cache directory /home/varun/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/, or directory is not writable. Proceeding without cache
Cannot create cache directory /home/varun/.composer/cache/files/, or directory is not writable. Proceeding without cache
Cannot create cache directory /home/varun/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/, or directory is not writable. Proceeding without cache
```

Comment: how did you install `composer`, did you use `sudo`?

Answer (score 1):

If the folder is owned by `root`, even if you have admin privileges, you still dont have permission, this happens when you use `sudo` while installing `composer`.

It can be solved by

```
sudo chown -R $USER $HOME/.composer
```

Comment: You are welcome!, dont forget to upvote this as answer that solved your problem.